# Difference between Exchange key and Signing key in Crypto API

Tags: .net, security, cryptography, cryptoapi

In the .NET crypto API, I noticed that the CspParameters object has a `KeyNumber` property that can be used to specify if the key should be a signing key or an exchange key.

Is there any real difference between the two as far as RSA keys are concerned?  Specifically, if I use an exchange key for signing is there something about the generated key that would make it inappropriate or insecure for that usage?

Comment: How are transporting the key? PFX/P12? Tokens?

Comment: @Raj - I'm exporting the keys as a Csp Blob. From there I'm storing them in a database with the private key encrypted using a separate AES key derived from the users password.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use an exchange key for signing. 
per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.keynumber.aspx), the exchange key is distributed to others so they can encrypt content to send to you. if they want to sign the message to indicate that they sent it, then they would use their own [Private key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Signing_messages) (signing key) to sign, and your public key to encrypt. in Diffie-Hellman terms, if you sign stuff with your public key, and then distribute/exchange it with others, they would be able to sign messages such that they appear to come from you. just think of the exchange key as your public, and the signing key as your private.

Comment: I think this applies if you are using the built-in security around stored keys to define who can an cannot access a key, whether or not they can use the private or public keys, and for what purposes.  In my case I'm exporting the key for use elsewhere so I'm more interested in the properties of the key itself and not the way the Crypto API manages security around the keys (hope that makes sense)